# Set Header Background and Text Color Using fancyhdr

Tags: color, fancyhdr

Is there any way to set the header background color using fancyhdr?

The [doc's don't make mention of color](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) so, I think I may be barking up the wrong tree. If fancyhdr can't do this are there any other package suggestions?

My preamble is very simple;

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\lhead{REST API Reference (v12.011918)}
\rhead{\thepage}
\cfoot{Company, Inc.}
```

I simply need to set the background to red and the text to white.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{fancyhdr,color}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength\headheight{17pt}
\lhead{
\textcolor{red}{\rule[-2pt]{\textwidth}{15pt}}%
\hspace{-\textwidth}%
\textcolor{white}{REST API Reference (v12.011918)}}
\rhead{\textcolor{white}{\thepage}}
\cfoot{Company, Inc.}
\begin{document}
zz
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @David! For those who want to remove the top horizontal bar in the header, you can use `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`

Answer (score 2):

Set the header in a `\colorbox{red}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Remove header/footer
\lhead{\colorbox{red}{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\color{white}%
    REST API Reference (v12.011918)
    \hfill
    \thepage
  }%
}}
\cfoot{Company, Inc.}

\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```