# Header with background color

Tags: header-footer, color, fancyhdr

I wanted to know whether there is a way to set the background color of my header.
Here is my code so far:

```tex
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\textsl{Title}}
\fancyhead[R]{\textsl{Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

Comment: I would gladly switch from fancyhdr to something else, if this is what i takes to get a background color.

Comment: have a look at the answer below based on -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411215/197451

Comment: off course I find `tikz` more intuitive as given here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527916/make-tikz-rectangle-fill-whole-paperwidth-including-margin/527919#527919

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{fancyhdr,color}
\usepackage{lastpage}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength\headheight{17pt}
\lhead{\textcolor{red}{\rule[-4pt]{\textwidth}{15pt}}%
\hspace{-\textwidth}%
\textcolor{white}{\textsl{Title}}}
\rhead{\textcolor{white}{\textsl{Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}}}

\begin{document}
zz
\end{document}
```

Comment: This somehow shifts "Title" a bit to the right, but the "Page of..." is completely on the left (and because of the italics a bit of the last character is outside the box)

Comment: Okay I found out why it shifted the "Title": I didn't have the code all in one line.
But, I could'nt figure out, how to move the "Page of..." more to the right.

Comment: Play with `phantom`. 
`\rhead{\textcolor{white}{\textsl{\Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}\phantom{xx}}}}`  will move the right header to the left to deal with the italics.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the header in a `\colorbox` in the centre *only*, and then spread the contents to the left/right/centre as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor}
\usepackage{lastpage,lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% Remove \fbox gap
  \colorbox{blue!15!white}{%
    \makebox[\textwidth]{%
      \rlap{\textsl{Title}}% Left header
      \hfill
      \clap{}% Center header
      \hfill
      \llap{\textsl{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}% Right header
    }% \makebox
  }% \colorbox
}% \fancyhead
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

All elements are placed with zero width (via `\rlap` for the left header, `\clap` for the centre and `\llap` for the right header) so as to not affect its placement relative to their width.

Comment: What exactly is a fbox?

Comment: I like this solution more, but I have one problem with it. How do I make the box taller?

Comment: @Brain: It's shorthand for a `f`ramed `box` that has a rule around it (of width `\fboxrule`) and a gap of `\fboxsep` between the rule and the box content. There is a more elaborate `\framebox` command as well that does the same thing with a set of optional arguments for the content width and alignment (similar to `\makebox`).

Comment: @Brain: It depends. If you just want a little more room, add a `\strut` just before `\rlap`. If you want it much taller, then one can insert a strut of your liking, but you'll also have to change `\headheight`. Removing the `\fboxsep` (setting it to `0pt` in my answer) makes the box tight against the content. One could use the default `\fboxsep` but, again, it may require a change in `\headheight` as well. You'll receive a warning to that effect in the `.log`. It can be circumvented, but you'll have to be specific about your needs though.

Comment: When I add a `\strut`, the header get's too long. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: @Brain: [This is what I mean by adding `\strut`](https://pastebin.com/raw/AM0mPxHe), which produces [this output for the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DilZX.png). What do you mean by "the header gets too long"?

Comment: Well, I have the [the following Code](https://pastebin.com/brRa5V81) and somehow the header is too long. [Here](https://imgur.com/FkUU9MK) is the output for the header.